# Pass param to Python script inside sh

Tags: python, bash

I need to pass param to a python function inside file sh.

My array is like this:

```
$ echo $myarr 
0, 17, 25, 28, 11, 19, 15, 2, 2, 2, 23, 27, 27, 8, 24, 15, 7, 13, 18, 27, 1, 23, 30, 21, 26, 19, 17, 27, 31, 25, 19, 6, 13
```

And the python function is like and its output is

```
$ python -c 'import bech32; print bech32.bech32_create_checksum("tb", ['$myarr'] )'
  File "<string>", line 1
    import bech32; print bech32.bech32_create_checksum("tb", [0,
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

If I use the array (without variable) it works

```
$ python -c 'import bech32; print bech32.bech32_create_checksum("tb", [0, 17, 25, 28, 11, 19, 15, 2, 2, 2, 23, 27, 27, 8, 24, 15, 7, 13, 18, 27, 1, 23, 30, 21, 26, 19, 17, 27, 31, 25, 19, 6, 13] )'
[10, 9, 20, 29, 27, 15]
```

[Here](https://github.com/sipa/bech32/blob/master/ref/python/segwit_addr.py#L49) you can see the python function

Comment: The version that works is different from what the shell see in the version that doen't work. For bash, you fed `python -c 'import bech32; print bech32.bech32_create_checksum("tb", ['0, 17, 25, 28, 11, 19, 15, 2, 2, 2, 23, 27, 27, 8, 24, 15, 7, 13, 18, 27, 1, 23, 30, 21, 26, 19, 17, 27, 31, 25, 19, 6, 13'] )'`

Comment: As you can see, you are passing multiple parameters, while the first one finishes just after the comma.

Comment: thanks! `python -c "import bech32; print bech32.bech32_create_checksum('tb', [$myarr] )"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quote with python cmd is wrong since it break the line. From this come the first error. Apart from this, to pass param to python cmd you can do this:

```
python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1])' "Now it should work"
```